# How to automatically add literal definitions, based on a single user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, user-defined-literals

`C++11` offers [user-defined literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#User-defined_literals). I've just started to play around with them, which made me wonder whether it would be possible to automatically add all [SI multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) to a single literal I define?

For example, if I define

```
Length operator "" _m(long double m) {
    return Length(m); // Length in meters
}
```

where `Length` is a subclass of some `Units` base class, I would like to have a mechanism to *automatically* add (in the same spirit as [boost operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)) SI multipliers for all literals that return a `Length`:

```
// these are added automatically when defining the literal "_m": 
                                         // Length in:
Length operator "" _Ym(long double Ym);  // Yottameters
Length operator "" _Zm(long double Zm);  // Zetameters
...                                      // ...
...                                      // ...
Length operator "" _km(long double km);  // kilometers
Length operator "" _mm(long double mm);  // millimeters
...                                      // ...       
...                                      // ...
Length operator "" _zm(long double zm);  // zeptometers
Length operator "" _ym(long double ym);  // yoctometers
```

As far as I could see, aside from perhaps some macro magic, there is no way to do this automatically since all user-defined literals need an *explicit* definition.

..or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Why not with templates?

Comment: Same as this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/447922/Application-of-Cplusplus11-User-Defined-Literals-t (if you can omit the unit of measure part and keep multiplier only...I missed that point, you're right we may need _macro magic_)

Comment: @Adriano: the template code doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a way to do exactly what you are asking for without "bizarre macros". This is as far as I could get:

```
template<typename T, T (*op)(long double)>
struct SI
{
    // ...
    constexpr static T micro = op (.000001);
    constexpr static T milli = op (.001);
    constexpr static T kilo = op (1000);
    constexpr static T mega = op (1000000);
    // ...
};

struct Length
{
    constexpr Length(long double d) : _d(d) { }
    constexpr operator long double() { return _d; }
    long double _d;
};

constexpr Length operator "" _m(long double m) {
    return Length(m);
}

typedef SI<Length, ::operator "" _m> SI_Length;

int main()
{
    constexpr Length l = 3 * SI_Length::kilo;
    static_assert(l == 3000, "error");
}
```

If bizarre macros are allowed, then something like the following should do the job:

```
#define DEFINE_SI_MULTIPLIERS(T, unit) \
    constexpr T operator "" _u ## unit(long double m) \
    { return ::operator "" _ ## unit(0.000001 * m); } \
    constexpr T operator "" _m ## unit(long double m) \
    { return ::operator "" _ ## unit(0.001 * m); } \
    constexpr T operator "" _k ## unit(long double m) \
    { return ::operator "" _ ## unit(1000 * m); } \
    // ...

DEFINE_SI_MULTIPLIERS(Length, m)

int main()
{
    constexpr Length l = 3.0_km;
    static_assert(l == 3000, "error");
}
```

Comment: hmm...nice attempt (+1), but this wouldn't be much different from simply multiplying with `const` SI factors defined in a namespace (e.g., `Length L = 3*si::kilo;`); IMHO it doesn't add much expressive power...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: True. As I mentioned, this is just as far as I could get, and that's probably not very far. I believe macros are the only way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: I believe so too. Accepted!

Answer (score -1):

Can't you use the `operator "" _m(const char *)` flavor as long as you're willing to parse the floats yourself?  That makes it possible to write `1234k_m` by calling out to a common SI-aware parser for your floating point values.

Comment: Are you sur this is supposed to work ? Using gcc 4.7.2 this is parsed as `1234` `k_m` and gcc looks for `operator"" k_m`, see [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1YjxLZ$0).