# Compilation failure with simple user-defined literal

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, iostream

I am seeing some behavior I can't quite explain. Consider `test.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
long double operator"" _N(long double a) { return a; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long double t = 4.0_N;
}
```

Issuing

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

gives me

```
test.cpp:2:22: error: expected suffix identifier
long double operator"" _N(long double V) { return V; }
                    ^
```

Making any of the the following changes will **NOT** give the error:

```
// #include <iostream>  // Is there some conflict with something in iostream then?
long double operator"" _N(long double a) { return a; }    
...

#include <iostream>
long double operator"" _P(long double a) { return a; } 
// (or most other letters and/or words) 
...
```

however, the problem persists for at least `_B` and `_C` (I didn't test the entire alphabet)...

What am I missing here?

More info:

```
$ g++ --version 
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
```

Running in CygWin on 64-bit Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: Names starting with underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the language and library implementation.

Comment: [See this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/440558).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: hmmm...so "names" includes user-defined literals then? Still seems odd, as the C++11 spec more or less mandates the use of an initial underscore for the names of user-defined literals... *it* says that literals *not* starting with an underscore are reserved for future standardization...

Comment: Clang 3.4 compiles your original code just fine.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: yes, it seems to depend on specific implementations  of `iostream`...

Comment: Can you try running it through the preprocessor only and show us what that gives?  g++ -E or so.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, because those identifiers starting with underscore-uppercase are meant for macros (think stuff like `_WIN32`) and those get expanded everywhere :( The reason the UDLs are required to start with underscore is consistency: the language already uses non-underscored suffixes (`f`, `l`, `u`, etc) so they decided to reserve the non-underscored UDL names. So in effect UDLs have to start with underscore + non-uppercase.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: that's really quite unfortunate...So this is also not something a namespace will be able to resolve (i.e., capture the UDL def in a namespace)?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: [here ya go](http://pastebin.com/USSiRcGQ)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes [not exactly a dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721584/user-defined-literals-underscores-and-global-names) but relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the preprocessed output you posted (http://pastebin.com/USSiRcGQ) we can see the problem right away:

```
long double operator "" 04(long double V) { return V; }
```

So you have some header file which does (the equivalent of) this:

```
#define _N 04
```

It would be interesting to know which header that is--you can try `grep -rw _N /usr/include` and see if it pops up.

Now that you know this, if you're brave I guess you could `#undef _N`, but really you should change to a suffix like `_n` or maybe something more descriptive.

Comment: Got it: `/usr/include/ctype.h`

Comment: Yup, I see it back in GCC 4.2 as well: http://www.filewatcher.com/p/arm-rtems-gcc-4.2.0_1.tbz.42779445/arm-rtems/include/ctype.h.html

Comment: Well, "descriptive" depends on context. I was trying to write a strong-typed system for physics units (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196955/)), where `Force P = 4.8_N;` would indicate a force of 4.8 Newtons (capital `N` is the [SI-standard symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) for Newtons). And lower-case `n` would be confusing, because that is the SI-standard notation for the "nano"-multiplier...Guess I'll have to live with some other notation.

Comment: Well your system itself could use a prefix within the suffix, like _zN for Newtons etc.  Single characters rarely make good identifiers in code anyway, even though they do make sense in written math/physics/etc.

Comment: 17.6.4.3.2
Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.